# Count Session Array through ajax.

Tags: php, ajax

I'm doing project for online food ordering system. I've made add to cart using session array and its functioning well. I'm using following code to count session so that user can know how many types of item are there in cart.

```
<?php echo sizeof($_SESSION['cart']); ?>
```

But using this code I need page to be refreshed for increase in session array count.

Now I want to know that is it possible to count that session array through ajax so that sessions count increases as soon as user add item to cart.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can done with this,

```
$.post( "count.php", function( data ) {
   console.log(data);
   $('#div_id').html(data); 
});
```

and in `count.php`

```
<?php
   session_start();
   echo sizeof($_SESSION['cart']);
?>
```

demo exapmle,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
       $.post( "count.php", function( data ) {
         console.log(data);
         $('.result').html(data); 
       });
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see response in console.and if you want to add response into div then see my edited answer.replace div_id with your div id.

Comment: is it necessay to put script in head tag. Because i am using tamplate. Yes console is showing desired output. But i cannot see it in my div. i've corrected my div id.

Comment: ok, you can put jquery into body also but wrap it into `<script></script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your php back end is this :

```
<?php
    $session_size = sizeof($_SESSION['cart']);
    echo json_encode(array(
        'size' => $session_size
    ));
?>
```

You can catch this value from client side without page refresh using ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/url_to_your_page.php",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json;",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.size);
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Something weird happen");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi. php file is working. It return {"size":3} . Ajax is not fetching this data. And, how can i show result in div.

Comment: yes i've changed all the mentioned and its working well. Thank u MD sir. I got alot from your answer.